# Where is the specification of the Synctex file format?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

In the context of a new LaTeX web-based IDE, we're writing a parser for Synctex.

Where can we find a specification or explanation of its structure and content in order to correctly parse it?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to just use (link to) the SyncTeX libraries rather than write your own parser?

Comment: Thanks Joseph, the thing is that we are in the browser, in Javascript :)

Comment: Official page (linked by _e.g._ TeXworks help) is http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html: does that help at all?

Comment: The link "Specifications" is broken.

Comment: @MartinMonperrus, it is an internal link to the same page, seems they have to put it on the page. So I'm guessing you need to look at those parser files on the page.

Comment: To some extent, 4000 lines of C code is an "executable" specification.

Comment: @JosephWright, expecting consumers of SyncTeX to either use a compiled binary or a library that is exclusively available in C is very 20th century. On top of that, the SyncTeX site hasn't been updated since 2004, despite containing remarks like "Enhancements should be expected." and "It will contain more material soon." That is exactly why open source needs open specifications, so others can work with it when the original author does not anymore.

Comment: @A.Donda The man page specifically says that the format should be regarded as internal (see https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/synctexdir/man5/synctex.5?revision=46371&view=markup, which is I guess the official source nowadays)

Comment: @JosephWright, yes, sorry, the comment shouldn't have been directed at you, you are completely correct. What I meant is that Jerome Laurens' policy is bad.

Answer (score 4):

There is a manual file:

```
man 5 synctex
```

also available at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/synctex.5.html

[original version control version](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/synctexdir/man5/synctex.5?revision=46371&view=markup)